# Pop-up menu: 1. Centering submenu instead of appearing directly above? 2. CSS3 fade only appearing on first row

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, fade

http://jsfiddle.net/pixeltramp/ge5zC/

Basically, I'm making a dropUP menu to be at the bottom of every page. First issue:
On hover, the menu's submenu pops up directly above, and I'd like the UL to be centered. No matter what I try though, it seems to either break or stay in position directly above.

As well, I have a corny little css3 fade-in effect on the menu, but it's only functioning on the first ul to appear, not every one.

Any help would be much appreciated! The entire thing is on the jsfiddle linked above.

```
 #block-menu-menu-bottom ul.menu li a {
padding: 0px 20px
}

#block-menu-menu-bottom ul.menu a:hover {

border-bottom: 0px solid #fff;
background:#333333;
}

#block-menu-menu-bottom li {
background-color: none;
-moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
-moz-border-left-colors: none;
-moz-border-right-colors: none;
-moz-border-top-colors: none;
border-color: none;
border-image: none;
border-right: none;
border-style: none;
border-width: none;
float: center;
display: inline-table;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
font: bold 16pt 'Helvetica';
}

ul.menu-bottom a {
padding: 0em 5px;
}

#block-menu-menu-bottom .content {
margin-bottom: 0;
}

#block-menu-menu-bottom {
display: table;
float: none;
margin: 0 auto;
}

/*#block-menu-menu-bottom div > ul > li + li {
margin-left: 40px;
}*/

#block-menu-menu-bottom a:hover {
 color:#ffffcc;   
}

            #block-menu-menu-bottom li {
                float: left;
                position: relative;
                width:100px;

            }

                    #block-menu-menu-bottom li ul {
                        position: absolute;
                        display:none;
                        width:800%;
                        -webkit-opacity: 0
                        -moz-opacity: 0;
                        opacity: 0;
                        -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
                        -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
                        -ms-transition: all .5s ease;
                        -o-transition: all .5s ease;
                        transition: all .5s ease;
                    }
                  #block-menu-menu-bottom li:hover ul {
                        bottom:100%;
                        display:block;
                        -webkit-opacity: 1;
                        -moz-opacity: 1;
                        opacity: 1;
                    }

                    #block-menu-menu-bottom li:hover ul li ul{
                        display:none;
                    }

                            #block-menu-menu-bottom li ul li a {
                                padding: 8px 000px;
                                line-height: 28px;
                            width: 5em;
                            }

                    #block-menu-menu-bottom ul li ul li ul{
                        display:none;


}

                    #block-menu-menu-bottom ul li ul li:hover ul {
                        display:block;
                        -webkit-opacity: 1;
                        -moz-opacity: 1;
                        opacity: 1;
}

                    #block-menu-menu-bottom ul li ul li ul li ul{
                        display:none;

}

                    #block-menu-menu-bottom ul li ul li ul li:hover ul {
                        display:block;

}

                    #block-menu-menu-bottom li ul li:hover ul li ul{
                        display:none;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Remove ID and give them CLASS

ID used to work for the first on.
But Class is for all.